# javascript - mail exchange server string validation using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

how can validate a mx server (similar to a domain) in the form of `mx*.m**p.com` by Regex? The first star can be any number without its length pre-defined 1, 11, 111, 1111, without leading 0s. The 2nd and 3rd stars are single letters in range of 0-9 and a-Z.

Examples:

- mx1.m0bp.com
- mx321.maBp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^mx[1-9][0-9]*\.m[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}p\.com$`

- `^` indicates the start of the string
- `mx` are the expected characters
- `[1-9]` The number must not have a leading zero, so it must start with 1-9
- `[0-9]*` Followed by zero or more other digits
- `\.` The dot must be escaped as it has a special meaning
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}` Exactly two characters with the given range
- `p\.com` again the next expected characters with another escaped dot
- `$` indicates the end of the string

Including the `^` and `$` means you won't get a match from `foomx1.m0bp.com` or `mx1.m0bp.comfoo`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below regex to test the domain:

```
mx[0-9]+\.m[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}p\.com
```

```js
console.log(/mx[0-9]+\.m[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}p\.com/gi.test("mx1.m0bp.com"))

console.log(/mx[0-9]+\.m[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}p\.com/gi.test("mx321.maBp.com"))
```

Comment: Did you read the question? "The first star can be any number without its length pre-defined 1, 11, 111, 1111, "**without leading 0s**"